# Strange X, Y, and Z data from an MMC5983MA

Tags: stm32

I am working on an  [MMC5983MA](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/821/Memsic_09102019_MMC5983MA_Datasheet_Rev_A-1635338.pdf) with an STM32.

I can read the product id (0x30) and temperature (0x7e = 25.8°C.)

The values are good.

When I read X, Y, and Z axis data, it is always close to 8G or -8G, which are the maximum and minimum gauss the device supports.

When I read the magnetic values in my phone, it is +- 0.2 ~ 0.5 G at my desk.

This is the sequence I use to read the data:

```
> magwritecontrol1 128   # SW_RST
> magwritecontrol0 2
> magreadstatus 2
00 12 
   ^^
   status in hex
> magreadtemp 3
ff 7e 10 
   ^^
   temp in hex
> magwritecontrol0 1
> magreadstatus 2
00 11 
   ^^
   status in hex
> magreadxyz 10
ff 83 3a 7c 4c 79 c4 cc 7e 10 
   ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^
   magX  magY  magZ
-7.7G, 7.7G, 7.6G
> magwritecontrol0 1
> magreadxyz 10
00 83 3a 7c 4e 79 c6 18 7e 10 
-77/10G, 77/10G, 76/10G
> magwritecontrol0 1
> magreadxyz 10
00 83 3a 7c 52 79 c7 90 7e 10 
-77/10G, 77/10G, 76/10G
>
```

Why is the value so big all the time?

Comment: I fail to understand the commands you're sending. E.g. what's the meaning of `2` in `> magreadstatus 2`? And what's the meaning of `10` in `> magreadxyz 10`. Add some more details so we can understand exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Looks like number of bytes to return

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry my explanation wasn't clear.
But I think I found my problem. The data sheet wasn't clear so I thought the 16 bits data is 2's complement integer number. But it is not. It has the offset(8G). I mean 0 output means -8G and 32767 output means 32767/4096 - 8 = 0 G and so on.
Thanks everybody for answering for my ugly question.